# Random matchmaking for a p2p chat application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a back-end developer (in PHP and Python) and I use JavaScript mostly for DOM manipulation.

Now I'm writing a chat app in Node.js and I'm not sure if my code is the cleanest.

Here is how it works:

- Users open the chat page;
- We will match them randomly to another user;
- They will chat p2p.

Here is what I have:

When the user opens the page and sends the `ready signal` to the server, it will add the user information to the `USERS` stack and add the user socket id (which I basically use as its id ) to the `QUEUE` object.

```
const USERS   = {};
const QUEUE   = {};
const MATCH   = [];
const CHATS   = {};

app.io.route('ready' , function (req){


    USERS[req.socket.id] = {
        username : req.data.username ,
        socket : req.socket.id ,
        req : req ,
    };

    QUEUE[req.socket.id] = req.socket.id ;

 })
```

Next there is a function to process the users in the queue and match them together. This function will grab the first user in the `QUEUE` (we call it primary user) and loop through the other users in the queue and when it finds another user (secondary user). It will add them to the `MATCH` array and remove them from the `QUEUE` and at the end calls the next function `match_making`.

```
var QUEUE_INPROG = false ;
function process_queue(){

    if(QUEUE_INPROG) return  ;
    QUEUE_INPROG = true  ;
    
    if( Object.keys(QUEUE).length < 2 )
    {
        QUEUE_INPROG = false ;
        return  ;
    }

    let primary_user = QUEUE[ Object.keys(QUEUE)[0] ];

    for (let secondary_user  in QUEUE) {

        if ( secondary_user != primary_user) {

            MATCH.push({
                primary   :  primary_user  ,
                secondary :  secondary_user,
            });

            delete QUEUE[secondary_user];
            delete QUEUE[primary_user];

            break ;
        }

    }

    QUEUE_INPROG = false ;
    match_making();

}


setInterval(()=>{
    process_queue();
} , 5000 );
```

The last function is pretty simple basically grabbing both users and sending their info to each other:

```
function match_making(){

    if(MATCH.length < 1 ) return  ;
    var match = MATCH.shift();

    let primary   = USERS[match.primary];
    let secondary = USERS[match.secondary];

    console.log('sending match data to users ');

    primary.req.io.emit('incoming_chat', { user  : secondary.username  })
    secondary.req.io.emit('incoming_chat', {user : primary.username })

    let chat_key = match.primary+match.secondary;
    CHATS[chat_key] = {

        primary   : primary ,
        secondary : secondary ,
        guest     : null

    };

}
```

I'm not happy about how I call functions and not sure if using an interval for calling `process_queue` is the best way to go. Also, I had to use a flag `(QUEUE_INPROG)` to avoid function being called again before the last call is done.

And how I have to use objects instead of array because I find it hard to search in an array and remove values.

I would love for someone with JS experience to take a look at this code and give me some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that stands out is the casing on variables that are declared like globals. Syntactically there is nothing wrong with it but a common convention in many style guides is to only use all caps for ([immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Immutable)) constants. This is recommended in many widely accepted style guides, not just for JavaScript (e.g. [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase), [AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--uppercase), [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-constant-names)) but also for Python ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)) and other C-based languages like PHP ([PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)).

The scope of variables can be reduced dramatically. Prefer using `const` over `let` and `var`. This helps anyone reading the code, including your future self, know what can be reassigned and what can’t. Refer to answers to [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/278652/244085) for more details.

The [shorthand property definition notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) can be used to simplify the lines like these where the key is the same as the name of the variable being referenced:

> ```
> CHATS[chat_key] = {
>
>        primary   : primary ,
>        secondary : secondary ,
>        guest     : null
>
> };
> ```

Can be simplified to:

```
CHATS[chat_key] = {

    primary,
    secondary,
    guest     : null

};
```

Also, the call to setup the interval can be simplified from wrapping the call in an anonymous function/closure:

> ```
> setInterval(()=>{
>     process_queue();
> } , 5000 );
> ```

To just referencing the function name:

```
setInterval(process_queue, 5000 );
```

> *…not sure if using an interval for calling `process_queue` is the best way to go. Also, I had to use a flag (`QUEUE_INPROG`) to avoid function being called again before the last call is done.*

Instead of an interval being set, `setTimeout()` could be used at the end of the function. That may eliminate the need for setting and checking the flag.

> *how I have to use objects instead of array because I find it hard to search in an array and remove values.*

A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could be used. A `Map` object iterates its elements in insertion order — a `for...of` loop returns an array of `[key, value]` for each iteration. <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#description)</sup>.

A [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) may also be useful. It may be able to help [eliminate memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29416340/1575353).

---

There is a loop in `process_queue()`:

> ```
> for (let secondary_user  in QUEUE) {
> ```

From the MDN documentation for [`for…in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#deleted_added_or_modified_properties):

> A `for...in` loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order (see the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting). <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#deleted_added_or_modified_properties)</sup>

If the code was run on the client-side and IE was supported then it would be possible that insertion order wouldn’t be guaranteed<sup>[3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#cross-browser_notes)</sup> . However this code is run on the node server, but in general it would be better to use a [`for…of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate over the keys.

```
for (const secondary_user of Object.keys(QUEUE)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

In the ready function, don't add to queue, call queue-handler with id.
pop your queue-**list** and if not undefined you've got a match.
else add the user to the queue.

Don't know if you need a `MATCH`-object at all. You're using it as temporary storage between functions instead of just passing parameters. Maybe you need it later?

You shouldn't need `setInterval` when every new, ready user triggers the process. And that might remove the need for `QUEUE_INPROG` variable.

You uppercase variables makes me as a javascript developer uncomfortable but that's ok :)

Comment: thanx , the thing is i might have multiple users online and ready at the same time , thats why i've put them in an queue object/array and have another function process them  to avoid some sort of race condition bug that might happen  if i call the queue-handler directly in the ready event

Comment: but it's a good idea to call the queue handler when user is ready and pass the id to handler  , pop the queue object in the handler function for match and if not found just add the new id to queue object  ... this way i dont need to use interval

Answer (score 2):

A longer review;

- Keep full uppercase names only for constant values like numbers
- In the `ready` function you access `req.socket.id` enough that you could store it locally
- To me, it is a code smell that you have the socket id in the key and in the value of USERS
- You mix `var` with `const` and `let`, I would stick with `const` and `let`
- JavaScript variables should be in lowerCamelCase so `primary_user` -> `primaryUser`
- `delete` was at some point considered obsolete, I try to avoid its use
- For a queue, I would use a list, not an object, I think the code could be so much simpler
- Magic numbers (like 5000) should be in a nicely named constant
- A match is just 2 objects, that seems unlikely to change, I would use an array instead of an object
- You should have a logging framework with log levels
- Actually, [globals are evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/7614), you should really look into that
- I prefer function names to follow `<verb><thing>` so `match_making` -> `makeMatches`
- YOu should realize that `()=>processQueue();` and `processQueue` are functionally equivalent, but the 2nd approach is cleaner and more readable
- You should read about the `async` keyword, I am fairly certain that you don't need `QUEUE_INPROG`. I left it in the rewrite, because I cant test the code

Taking that into account;

Part 1;

```
const socketUsers = {};
const queue   = {};
const matches = [];
const chats   = {};

app.io.route('ready' , function (request){

  id = request.socket.id;
    socketUsers[id] = {
        username : request.data.username,
        socket : id ,
        req : request,
    };
    //Drawback of a list, it does not natively weed out dupes
    if(!queue.includes(id)){
      queue.push(id);
    }
 })
```

Part 2;

```
let queueLocked = false ;
const queueProcessInterval = 5000;
function processQueue(){

    if(queueLocked || queue.length < 2){
      return;
    }
    queueLocked = true;

    matches.push([queue.pop(), queue.pop()]);

    queueLocked = false ;
    makeMatches();
}


setInterval(processQueue, queueProcessInterval);
```

Part 3;

```
function makeMatches(){

    while(matches.length){
      const match = matches.pop();
      const primary = users[match.pop()];
      const secondary = users[match.pop()];

      //You should have a logging framework with log levels
      //console.log('sending match data to users ');

      primary.req.io.emit('incoming_chat', { user  : secondary.username  })
      secondary.req.io.emit('incoming_chat', {user : primary.username })

      const chatKey = primary.socket + secondary.socket;
      //This will make guest `undefined`, not null, I am not a fan of null
      chats[chatKey] = {primary, secondary, guest};

    }
}
```

Comment: about the function names `<verb><thing>` like ` match_making -> makeMatches` i think starting  with `thing`  kinda works like namespace  ,  makes it easier to find/group the functions about that `thing`